# Finding The Sum in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working on a code with trying to find the sum of the numbers:

-817930511,
1771717028,
4662131,
-1463421688,
1687088745

I have put them in a separate file as I should but I am confused as to why my code is not working.

```
#finding the sum
def main():
filename = input("Please enter your file name: ")
openthefile=open(filename,'r')
sum_number=0
for line in openthefile:
    for the number in line.split(","):
        sum_number=sum_number+float(numbers.strip()
print('The sum of your numbers is', sum_number)


main()
```

I keep getting the syntax error appearing on the 7th line of code
I have changed it around some there too but can't seem to see what is wrong.

Comment: it should be `number.strip()` and `for number in ...`

Comment: I have changed what you suggest but it now says invalid syntax still highlighting the number in the 7ht line.

Comment: First of all the indentation is wrong, at least in the example you have provided. As @VanPeer mentioned `for the number` will throw an error. That's wrong syntax. Also calling `numbers.strip()` will throw NameError. You don't have any variable with the name `numbers` in your code.

Comment: And you missed a ) after number.strip() that clauses the cast to float.

Answer (score 2):

Simplified using [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum) and - more importantly - [`strip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.strip):

```
def main():
    # ...
    s = sum(float(l.strip(', \n')) for l in openthefile)
    print('The sum of your numbers is', s)
```

This strips away the comma `','`, spaces `' '` (just to be safe), and the linebreak `'\n'` at the end of each line before turning the remainder into a float.

Answer (score 1):

Input file

```
-817930511, 1771717028, 4662131, -1463421688, 1687088745,
```

Code

```
#finding the sum
def main():
    filename = input("Please enter your file name: ")
    openthefile=open(filename,'r')
    b=0
    for line in openthefile:
        a = ([float(x) for x in line.split(',') if x])
        b = sum(a)
    print("The sum of your numbers is", b)

main()
```

Output

```
The sum of your numbers is 1182115705.0
```